# SherlockFragmentActivity, reject tab change in onTabSelected

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock

I have a tabbar where 1 tab opens the camera in a new activity.  When this tab is selected, I want that tab selection to be rejected, and it want the tab that was previously selected to stay selected.

I have an `activeFragment` variable, which I tried using to reselect the tab that was previously selected using `getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0);`  But this doesn't work.  I've tried NOT calling `ft.commit()` when the CAMERA tab is selected, but this doesn't work either.  How can I reject this tab from being selected, or at the very least, immediately reselect the tab that was previously selected?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To reselect a tab in onTabSelected() when realizing a tab isn't allowed to be selected yet, I found you can use something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        boolean bOK = true;
        if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
            if (!checkReadyToChangeTab()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot change tab!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bOK = false;
                // reselect tab 0
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        getSupportActionBar().selectTab(getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(0));
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10);
            }
        }
        if (bOK) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }
    }
```